# How to run cli command from package without global install using npx

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npx

I'm trying to run a cli command from `@foal/cli` using npx to avoid global installation.

Following [the docs](https://foalts.gitbook.io/docs/tutorials/simple-to-do-list/1-installation) I should do the following:

```sh
$ npm install -g @foal/cli

$ foal createapp my-app
```

I'm trying to use `npx` to avoid global installation of package.

Following [this article](https://dev.to/tallyb/when-to-use-global-npm-installs-rarely-2dm3) I tried the following:

```sh
$ npx -package @foal/cli foal createapp foal-test
npx: installed 203 in 27.122s
'foal' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `npx --package` or `npx -p` for short.